# In what way does this program access illegal memory?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, openmp

Currently I'm learning about C and OpenMP. I wrote the following program:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 960

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int nthreads, tid, i, j;
    double a[N][N];

/* Fork a team of threads */
    #pragma omp parallel shared(nthreads) private(i,tid,a)
    {
        tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        if (tid == 0) 
        {
            nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
            printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
            
        }
        printf("Thread %d starting...\n", tid);
        
        #pragma omp for
        for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            for (j=0; j<N; j++)
            {
                a[i][j] = tid + i + j;
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile the code it compiles. I use in a Linux terminal:

```
gcc name.c -o name -lm -fopenmp
```

When I want to excecute the program I get a segmentation error. I searched for a definition:

*A segmentation fault occurs when a program attempts to access a memory location that it is not allowed to access, or attempts to access a memory location in a way that is not allowed*

I don't really see how I try to access a memory that is not allowed. Could I please get feedback on why I get a segmentation error?

Comment: `double a[N][N];` is about 7.3 megabytes.

Comment: @KamilCuk I mean, that alone is not a problem...

Comment: `a` should be `shared` I believe. And `j` should definitely be `private`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Linux stack is what, 8Mb? Of course it's the problem.

Comment: Replace the local array with `double (*a)[N] = malloc( sizeof(double[N][N]) );` ... `free(a);`.

Comment: @lundin I run it on a virtual machine on my own laptop. Are those 8mb's still a issue then?

Comment: @Lundin exactly ;) missing that little piece of information. On x86 32bit it's probably even less than that IIRC.

Comment: @Terr070 The issue is that you shouldn't declare huge arrays locally on any kind of system.